# While loop checking JBoss status down or not, giving error

Tags: shell-script

The intention of the following code is to check status of JBoss, the while loop iterates until the JBoss status comes to the 'DOWN' state.
    `
I have the following script, which I've set to this environment variable so that I can make use of it, vs the actual path to the script:

```
$ JBOSS_ROOT=/opt/app/jboss/jboss.sh
```

*script*

```
time=1
while  [ $JBOSS_ROOT status | egrep -nq "DOWN"  ]
  do
        echo "JBoss stooping, please wait ......."
        sleep 1m
        if [ $time -gt 6 ]
         then
            echo "Something went wrong.. it's been running more than 5 \
                minutes, please check JBoos server log and deployments"
            exit
        fi

        time=$(expr "$time" + 1)
  done

echo "JBoss stopped"
`
```

- `$JBOSS_ROOT status` returns "JBoss DOWN" if JBoss in down (stop position).
- `$JBOSS_ROOT status` returns "JBoss (pid:32627) is RUNNING" if JBoss is in running (start position).

Throwing error at while loop. saying that `./stop.sh: line 5: [: missing`]'`.

Answer (score 1):

You have your format wrong. Try this instead:

```
while  $JBOSS_ROOT status | grep -Enq "DOWN" 
do
    ...
done
```

The `[ ]` is not needed (and does not work) here. That's only for testing.